# How to select all the elements in the DOM except one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an jQuery events) that are triggering on every DOM element on the page.
That's fine for now, but I need a way to exclude a div (with child divs as well) from DOM selection in order to prevent triggering event on them.
I've tried jQuery's `unbind()`, `not()` and `off()` directly on `$('#myDiv')`, but the events are still triggering.

The code that triggers the event(s):

```
$("*").each(function () {
       // here are events bound to every DOM in the page
       $(this).mouseover(mouseover).mouseout(mouseout).click(click);
    });
```

I've also tried with

```
$("*:not(#myDiv)").each(function () {
       // events 
       $(this).mouseover(mouseover).mouseout(mouseout).click(click); 
    });
```

and still wasn't able to remove events from #myDiv.

The HTML:

```
 <div id="myDiv">
      <div class="data">
          <!-- -->
      </div>
      <div class="debug">
          <!-- -->
      </div>
      <div class="form">
          <!-- -->
      </div>

 </div>
```

What is the best way to make full DOM selection but **excluding** #myDiv, so I would be able to use `bind()` or `on()` for binding events?

**NOTE:** I don't want to remove #myDiv from the DOM tree, but rather exclude it from selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
    $('body > *').not('#myDiv')
    .on('mouseover', function(){ //... })
    .on('click', function(){ //... });  
});
```

[**An Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/HD52U/)

Answer (score 2):

Try [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
    $("*").not("#myDiv").each(function () {
       $(this).mouseover(mouseover).mouseout(mouseout).click(click); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude the children as well, you'll need to do so explicitly:

```
$("*:not(#myDiv):not(#myDiv *)")
```

Comment: Already tried that, but the events still trigger, most probably on #myDiv children

Comment: @dede Ah, I see, you want to exclude the children. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$("*:not(#myDiv):not(#myDiv *)")
    .mouseover(mouseover)
    .mouseout(mouseout)
    .click(click)
```

This will exclude not only #myDiv, but any child elements of #myDiv (which you seem to be going for).